# Trim version using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i need to fetch the first two octets of an version.

For example "4.12.4.5" to "4.12".

How do I do that using LINQ?

Currently, i am using the following piece of code, but it is not completely LINQ.

```
var Version = "2.45.1.2";
char seperator = '.';
var splitVersion = Version.Split(seperator).Take(2).ToList();
var trimmedVersion = splitVersion[0]  + "." + splitVersion[1];
```

**Update**:

Answer using [Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) Class:

> var systemVersion = new Version("2.45.1.44");
>
> var trimmedVersion = systemVersion.Major + "." + systemVersion.Minor;

Answer (score 11):

> How do I do that using LINQ?

Why LINQinq, trimming, splitting, joining, regexing and I don't know what else when you have the [`Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) class and its [`Major`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.major.aspx) and [`Minor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.minor.aspx) properties?

```
var version = new Version("2.45.1.2");
string trimmedVersion = version.ToString(2);
```

The [`.ToString(int fieldCount)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bff8h2e1.aspx) method allows you to take only the numbers of this version that you are interested in.

Comment: You can use `version.ToString(2)` where 2 is the `fieldcount` instead of `string.Concat`.

Comment: @shamp00, excellent remark! Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer to take it into account.

Comment: Wow @shamp00, I was unaware of that `ToString` overload. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `How do I do that using LINQ?`

```
var Version = "2.45.1.2";
char seperator = '.';
var splitVersion = Version.Split(seperator).Take(2).ToArray().Aggregate((i, j) => i + "." + j);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    var Version = "2.45.1.2";
    char seperator = '.';
    var splitVersion = Version.Split(seperator);
    var trimmedVersion = string.Join(".", splitVersion.Take(2));
    Console.WriteLine(trimmedVersion);
}
```

Although what you had before works...There is no need to pull in Linq.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Version v = new Version("2.45.1.2");
var strippedversion = v.Major.ToString() +"."+ v.Minor.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(strippedversion);
Console.ReadKey();
```